# Js - Translate scrollTop to opacity level

Tags: javascript

I have this function that sets the opacity level of a `div`to the current `scrollTop`of its parent.

```
$('.container').scroll(function() {
    var this_panel_cont_    = $(this).get(0);
    var scrolldepth_        = this_panel_cont_.scrollTop; 
    var fade_out_           = parseInt(scrolldepth_ / 10) / 10;
    $('.panel').css({'opacity':fade_out_});
});
```

I get an output of min `0.0` to max `3.5`, but I need a max of `1.0` since opacity goes from `0.0` to `1.0`.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can add an if statement for the fade_out_  variable like this

```
$('.container').scroll(function() {
    var this_panel_cont_    = $(this).get(0);
    var scrolldepth_        = this_panel_cont_.scrollTop; 
    var fade_out_           = parseInt(scrolldepth_ / 10) / 10;
    if(fade_out_ > 1){fade_out_ = 1;} else{fade_out_ = parseInt(scrolldepth_ / 10) / 10;}
    $('.panel').css({'opacity':fade_out_});
});
```

I haven't tried this code but it should do the work.

Comment: Thank you very much, but what about the scroll depth from `1.0` to `3.5` ? Your solution won't fade out the `div` accurately, but ~70% too fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate how much percent of an element was scrolled and use that:

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
$(".container").scroll(function(){
    var percent = e.scrollTop / (e.scrollHeight - e.clientHeight);
    $(".panel").css({ "opacity": percent });
});
```

(I don't know the corresponding jQuery functions for `scrollHeight` and `clientHeight` which is why I used `document.getElementsByClassName`)

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cj604bhr/

Comment: @pyjama No problem! If this did actually resolve your problem, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer :)

Comment: Isn't there a mathematical formula that I can use also in other cases where I don't have let's say the `clientHeight`?

Comment: @pyjama clientHeight is basically the inner height of the element. All elements should have that property.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but what about cases where I'm not dealing with elements at all?

Comment: @pyjama Like what? If you want to adapt that calculation for like the whole document, you'd use the document height as the scrollHeight and the window height as the clientHeight. [here](https://codepen.io/achudars/pen/Cpast?editors=1010) is an example.

Comment: No, I mean how to translate a data flow from `0.0` - `3.5` to  `0.0` - `1.0`

Comment: @pyjama Well, in that case you'd perform a normal percentage calculation. 0.0 is 0% and 3.5 is 100%. You divide the desired value by 3.5. I made a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aq5nwyr2/).